# How to delaying Android UI update when remove and add new children to Layout Container?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I'm developing UI with FlowLayout

When I click some button, I change the children of the Flowlayout.

```
flowLayout.removeAllChildren();

for(int i in newChilds.size()) {
   View newChildView = ...
   flowLayout.addView(newChildView);
}
```

Then Flowlayout becomes a white screen for a short time and then fills with other child views.

What I want is delaying UI update so that the child view is filled and then displayed on the screen

How can I make it???

Comment: Have you tried a loader or a progress bar

Comment: @Ibrahim117 progressbar will be showing on the flowlayout